# To mock AWS SES with Sinon

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, sinon, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-mock

I'm trying to mock SES with Sinon, but facing below error. Tried using aws-sdk-mock, but it's not working.

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property sendEmail
```

Code snippet of test class:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
sandbox.stub(AWS.SES, 'sendEmail').returns({promise: () => true});
```

Actual class:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import * as _ from 'lodash';    

export async function sendAlertMailOnFailure(status:any)
{   
    // load AWS SES
    var ses = new AWS.SES();   
    const params = {
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: <to_address>
        },
        Message: {...},    
        Source: <sender_address>
      }
      ses.sendEmail(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          log.error("Error sending mail::");
          log.error(err, err.stack);
        }
      })
}
```

Is there any way to mock SES with Sinon or with aws-sdk-mock?

Comment: Show your business logic code where you are using the AWS SES

Answer (score 1):

My answer here is not a direct solution for `SES`, but it *is* a working solution I'm using for mocking `DynamoDB.DocumentClient` and `SQS`. Perhaps you can adapt my working example for `SES` and other `aws-sdk` clients in your unit tests.

I just spent hours trying to get AWS SQS mocking working, *without* resorting to the `aws-sdk-mock` requirement of importing `aws-sdk` clients inside a function.

The mocking for `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` was pretty easy, but the `AWS.SQS` mocking had me stumped until I came across the suggestion to use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire).

My lambda moves bad messages to a SQS FailQueue (rather than letting the Lambda fail and return the message to the regular Queue for retries, and then DeadLetterQueue after maxRetries). The unit tests needed to mock the following SQS methods:

- `SQS.getQueueUrl`
- `SQS.sendMessage`
- `SQS.deleteMessage`

I'll try to keep this example code as concise as I can while still including *all* the relevant parts:

Snippet of my AWS Lambda (index.js):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region:'eu-west-1'});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({ apiVersion: '2012-11-05' });
// ...snip
```

Abridged Lambda event records (event.json)

```
{
    "valid": {
        "Records": [{
            "messageId": "c292410d-3b27-49ae-8e1f-0eb155f0710b",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBz5JUoLYsn4dstTAxP7/IF9+T1S994n3FLkMvMmAh1Ut/Elpc0tbNZSaCPYDvP+mBBecVWmAM88SgW7iI8T65Blz3cXshP3keWzCgLCnmkwGvDHBYFVccm93yuMe0i5W02jX0s1LJuNVYI1aVtyz19IbzlVksp+z2RxAX6zMhcTy3VzusIZ6aDORW6yYppIYtKuB2G4Ftf8SE4XPzXo5RCdYirja1aMuh9DluEtSIW+lgDQcHbhIZeJx0eC09KQGJSF2uKk2BqTGvQrknw0EvjNEl6Jv56lWKyFT78K3TLBy2XdGFKQTsSALBNtlwFd8ZzcJoMaUFpbJVkzuLDST1y4nKQi7MK58JMsZ4ujZJnYvKFvgtc6YfWgsEuV0QSL9U5FradtXg4EnaBOnGVTFrbE18DoEuvUUiO7ZQPO9auS4=",
            "body": "{ \"key1\": \"value 1\", \"key2\": \"value 2\", \"key3\": \"value 3\", \"key4\": \"value 4\", \"key5\": \"value 5\" }",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1536763724607",
                "SenderId": "AROAJAAXYIAN46PWMV46S:steve.goossens@bbc.co.uk",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1536763724618"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "e5b16f3a468e6547785a3454cfb33293",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:123456789012:sqs-queue-name",
            "awsRegion": "eu-west-1"
        }]
    }
}
```

Abridged unit test file (test/index.test.js):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const LamdbaTester = require('lambda-tester');
const rewire = require('rewire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const event = require('./event');
const lambda = rewire('../index');

let sinonSandbox;

function mockGoodSqsMove() {
    const promiseStubSqs = sinonSandbox.stub().resolves({});
    const sqsMock = {
        getQueueUrl: () => ({ promise: sinonSandbox.stub().resolves({ QueueUrl: 'queue-url' }) }),
        sendMessage: () => ({ promise: promiseStubSqs }),
        deleteMessage: () => ({ promise: promiseStubSqs })
    }
    lambda.__set__('sqs', sqsMock);
}

describe('handler', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        sinonSandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sinonSandbox.restore();
    });

    describe('when SQS message is in dedupe cache', function () {
        beforeEach(() => {
            // mock SQS
            mockGoodSqsMove();
            // mock DynamoDBClient
            const promiseStub = sinonSandbox.stub().resolves({'Item': 'something'});
            sinonSandbox.stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'get').returns({ promise: promiseStub });
        });

        it('should return an error for a duplicate message', function () {
            return LamdbaTester(lambda.handler)
                .event(event.valid)
                .expectReject((err, additional) => {
                    expect(err).to.have.property('message', 'Duplicate message: {"Item":"something"}');
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In my example, the Lambda is index.js, and it has module.exports including the handler function. In the test file, `const lambda = rewire('../index');` is the rewired lambda, which is tested with LambdaTester

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `prototype` in `AWS` to stub it:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
sandbox.stub(AWS.prototype, 'SES').returns({
  sendEmail: () => {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Got error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Comment: have you installed `aws-sdk`?

Comment: Yes. it's installed. With DynamoDB, it worked fine. >> sandbox.stub(DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'update').returns({promise: () => true});

Comment: Error: Trying to stub property 'SES' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate that `AWS` is being imported as `undefined`.

It might be that your ES6 compiler isn't automatically turning this line:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

...into an import of everything in `aws-sdk` into `AWS`.

Change it to this:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
```

...and that may fix the issue.

---

(Disclaimer: I can't reproduce the error in my environment which is compiling with `Babel` v7 and automatically handles either approach)

Comment: Getting this error now >>  TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property SES. Tried using aws-sdk-mock, but it's not working and calling the original method.

Answer (score 0):

Using require & without using prototype. This is working for me for mocking DynamoDB.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();

this.awsStub = sandbox.stub(aws, 'DynamoDB').returns({
  query: function() {
    return {
      promise: function() {
        return {
          Items: []
        };
      }
    };
  }
});
```

**Packages**:

"aws-sdk": "^2.453.0"

"sinon": "^7.3.2"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use awk-sdk-mock by doing the following:

test class

```
const AWSMock = require('aws-sdk-mock');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);

...

    AWSMock.mock('SES', 'sendRawEmail', mockSendEmail);
// call method that needs to mock send an email goes below
    sendEmail(to, from, subject, body, callback);

function mockSendEmail(params, callback) {
    console.log('mock email');
    return callback({
        MessageId: '1234567',
    });
}
```

Actual class

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


function sendEmail(to, from, subject, body, callback) {
    let addresses = to;
    if (!Array.isArray(addresses)) {
        addresses = [addresses];
    }
    let replyTo = [];
    if (from) {
        replyTo.push(from);
    }

    let data = {
        to: addresses,
        replyTo,
        subject,
        text: body,
    };

    nodemailer.createTransport({ SES: new aws.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' }) }).sendMail(data, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
...
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
sandbox.stub(AWS, 'SES').returns({
    sendRawEmail: () => {
        console.log("My sendRawEmail");
        return {
            promise: function () {
                return {
                    MessageId: '987654321'
                };
            }
        };
    }
});
let ses = new AWS.SES({ region: 'us-east-1' });
let result = ses.sendRawEmail(params).promise();
```